# Framework7 Page Fully Loaded

Tags: javascript, callback, phonegap, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 and Phonegap for creating an app. I have page which loaded with JSON data from server and I need to hide preloader after whole page loaded with pictures and scripts. Data is loading with `onPageBeforeInit` callback and I tried `preloader.hide()` in `onPageInit()` callback and also `$$(document).on('pageAfterAnimation')`. I  alos tried `window.load`, binding and `$$(document).('DOMContentLoaded')` but none of these working.

Which event will do this work? Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you should hide the preloader the moment you finish getting the data from the server. it must be app.dialog.close(); for F7 v2 or app.hidePreloader(); for F& v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide Loader inside when the request is made and response comes back
For Framework 7 v3 it will be
// Showing loader
app.preloader.show("green");

```
app.request.post("url", {"data to send"}, function (data) {
     //Here the response comes so hide loader
     app.preloader.hide();
});
```

I am using this and working Fine for me